# Random number generator generating the same number inside of a for loop

Tags: python, numpy, random, numbers

I've implemented a Monte Carlo strategy to estimate the parameters of a model given an initial point of suboptimal parameters. To assess the different conditions around this optimum, I used the numpy.random.uniform(min, max) random number generator, as shown in the code below:

```
for j in range(iterations): print(" PERFORMING ITERATION: " + str(j+1)+' OF '+ str(iterations) )#+ (" - CASE: " + str(count) + " / " + str(len(aux_it))))
    # WIDE PARAMETRIC SPACE
    parameters = []
    for k in list(ap.keys()):
        p_0 = np.random.uniform(ap[k][0],ap[k][1])
        parameters.append(p_0)


    if True:
        with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.simplefilter('error')
            print('parameters: ',parameters)

            mse,var1,var2 = ridge_mse2(np.array(parameters),tagsUext,P1)
```

I noticed that starting from j=1 onwards, the value of 'parameters' didn't change.

I only managed to solve this problem when I set the seed of the random number generator before starting the 'for' loop to construct 'parameters', as shown in the code below:

```
for j in range(iterations): print(" PERFORMING ITERATION: " + str(j+1)+' OF '+ str(iterations) )#+ (" - CASE: " + str(count) + " / " + str(len(aux_it))))

    # WIDE PARAMETRIC SPACE
    parameters = []
    np.random.seed(j)
    for k in list(ap.keys()):
        p_0 = np.random.uniform(ap[k][0],ap[k][1])
        parameters.append(p_0)
    
    
    if True:
        with warnings.catch_warnings():
            warnings.simplefilter('error')
            print('parameters: ',parameters)
    
            mse,var1,var2 = ridge_mse2(np.array(parameters),tagsUext,P1)
```

Could someone explain to me why this happens?

Comment: please show us what's in ap

Comment: ap is a dictionary with the minimum and maximum value for each parameter within 'parameter'


    ap = {str(i):[tudo[i]*0.85,tudo[i]*1.15] for i in range(len(tudo))}

Comment: Hi Ana, I corrected my answer. Maybe it is more useful now

Comment: I can't replicate this, for example: https://www.ideone.com/6rOvLT Are you sure the code you are running is exactly what is in the question?